# How many conversation objects holds, one application endpoint?

Tags: ucma

I am using UCMA 4.0 currently. I am developing on sample based on UCMA 4.0. In that sample I need 4 conversation objects to connect a one call with my application.
So I want know how may conversation objects hold an one application endpoint in UCMA 4.0? So that I will know, how may calls an one application endpoint going to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a limit to the number of active "conversations" a UMCA endpoint can be used at any one time.

Having multiple active conversations in a UMCA application, is what I would consider normal usage.